# Following Tutorial, {{on}} modifier not working

Tags: ember.js

I just got into ember.js recently and I've been following their tutorial.

However, in the interactive components section, I came across some errors.

The below is my ***image.hbs*** file

```
{{#if this.isLarge}}
  <button type="button" class='image' {{on 'click' this.toggleSize()}}>
    <img ...attributes>
    <small>View Smaller</small>
  </button>
{{else}}
  <button type="button" class="image" {{on 'click' this.toggleSize()}}>
    <img ...attributes>
    <small>View Larger</small>
  </button>
{{/if}}
```

The below is my ***image.js*** code

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class RentalImageComponent extends Component {
  @tracked isLarge = false;

  @action toggleSize() {
    this.isLarge = !this.isLarge;
  }
}
```

The error message reads:

> Build Error (broccoli-persistent-filter:Babel > [Babel:
> super-rentals]) in super-rentals/components/rental/image.js
>
> ### /Users/joohyunkoh/Documents/ember-projects/super-rentals/super-rentals/components/rental/image.js:
> Parse error on line 2:
> ..." {{on 'click' this.toggleSize()}}>
>
> Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'Error:
> /Users/joohyunkoh/Documents/ember-projects/super-rentals/super-rentals/components/rental/image.js:
> Parse error on line 2:
> ..." {{on 'click' this.toggleSize()}}>
> -----------------------^
> Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'

If anyone can let me know what I might be doing wrong, that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Ember! and thanks for trying the tutorial! <3

looks like you have extraneous parenthesis!

Try making these changes:

```
  {{#if this.isLarge}}
-   <button type="button" class='image' {{on 'click' this.toggleSize()}}>
+   <button type="button" class='image' {{on 'click' this.toggleSize}}>
      <img ...attributes>
        <small>View Smaller</small>
    </button>
  {{else}}
-   <button type="button" class="image" {{on 'click' this.toggleSize()}}>
+   <button type="button" class="image" {{on 'click' this.toggleSize}}>
      <img ...attributes>
      <small>View Larger</small>
    </button>
  {{/if}}
```

or more precisely:

change `this.toggleSize()` to `this.toggleSize`

I don't know if this would help, but I made a syntax guide: https://cheatsheet.glimmer.nullvoxpopuli.com/docs/templates

Comment: Thank you so much!! Literally helped so much. Thank you for such a warm welcome to the community!